# Using .title() on a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file where I want:

- the first letter of every name to be be capitalized and
- the other letters to be lowercase.

I have tried using `.title()`.

The CSV file that I want to have the capital letters (CleanNames.csv) will be 'pulling' these names from another CSV (ValidNames.csv) which is 'pulling' those names from a list of disorganized names (10000DirtyNames.csv).

Here is what I have so far:

```
import re
import csv

with open("10000DirtyNames.csv", "r") as file:

    with open('ValidNames.csv', 'w+') as ValidNames_file:
        write = csv.writer(ValidNames_file, delimiter=',');
        data = file.read();
        pattern = "[A-Za-z]{1,}";
        search = re.findall(pattern, data);
        write.writerow(search);

        with open('CleanNames.csv', 'w') as CleanNames_file:
            write2 = csv.writer(CleanNames_file, delimiter=',');
            data2 = ValidNames_file.read();
            write2.writerow(data2.title());
```

It works except the CleanName.csv is not being populated at all. There is no error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `open()` mode should be `wb` not `w`, though this only matters on some operating systems.  Show us a small example file.

Comment: Do you mean it should be `w` not `w+`? Thanks, I solved the problem though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own but thought I would post my solution encase someone every needed to solve a similar problem.

```
import re
import csv



with open("10000DirtyNames.csv", "r") as file:

    with open('ValidNames.csv', 'w+') as ValidNames_file:
        write = csv.writer(ValidNames_file, delimiter=',');
        data = file.read();
        pattern = "[A-Za-z]{1,}";
        search = re.findall(pattern, data);
        write.writerow(search);

        with open('ValidNames.csv') as ValidNames_file, open('CleanNames.csv', 'w') as CleanNames_file:
            for name in ValidNames_file:
                CleanNames_file.write(name.title())
```